# Why the char *str; is declared as out of bounds

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to debug this function which is a part of another program and I'm getting a "**Segmentation fault**" error from the pointer `str` which appears in the watches window as out of bounds. The error happens when I use `strcmp` with `str` as an argument. What am I doing wrong?

```
char **merge(int R, int C, char ***mat)
     {
         char **tmp;
         char *str;
         int *trace, i=0, j, min;

         tmp = (char **)malloc(R * C * sizeof(char *));
         if(tmp == NULL)
         {
             fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error\n");
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }

         trace = (int *)malloc(R *sizeof(int));
         if(trace == NULL)
         {
             fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error\n");
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }

         for(i = 0; i < R; i++)
         {
             trace[i] = 0;
         }

         i = 0;
         while(i < (R*C))
         {
             for(j = 0; j < R; j++)
             {
                 if(trace[j] < C)
                 {
                    if(strcmp(mat[j][trace[j]], str) < 0 )
                     {
                        str = mat[j][trace[j]];
                        min = j;
                     }
                 }
             }
             tmp[i++] = mat[min][trace[min]];
             trace[min]++;
         }

         free(trace);
         return tmp;
     }
```

Update: why is this second piece of code, which is the solution the professor provided, working and yet the pointer is also not initialized?

```
/*
 *  merge the matrix rows into a sorted array
 */
char **merge_matrix(char ***matrix, int R, int C)
{
  int i, j, min_idx, *idx;
  char **array, *min_word;

  /* allocate the final array, plus an auxiliary one */
  array = (char **)malloc(R * C * sizeof(char *));
  idx = (int *)calloc(R, sizeof(int));
  if ((array == NULL) || (idx == NULL)) {
    printf("Memory allocation error.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* merge the matrix rows */
  i = 0;
  while (i < R*C) {

        min_idx = -1;

        for (j=0; j<R; j++) {

            if (idx[j] < C) {

                if ((min_idx==-1) || (strcmp(matrix[j][idx[j]], min_word)<0)) {
                    min_idx = j;
                    min_word = matrix[min_idx][idx[min_idx]];
                }

            }

        }

        array[i++] = matrix[min_idx][idx[min_idx]++];
    }

  free(idx);
  return array;
}
```

Comment: `tmp` is double pointer, you allocated memory only for `tmp` not for  `tmp[0]`.

Comment: You don’t initialize `str` to point to anything before you use it, AFAICS. This is a recipe for crashing.

Comment: str is declared at the top of the function, but not initialised. This means it will have whatever garbage that that memory location previously held. So the first strcmp using str as an argument will be using a pointer that could point to anywhere in memory.

Comment: consider using tools like valgrind for these type of issues.

Comment: I agree with you on the initialization point  but why the other code works without "segmentation fault" and its pointer is unintialized?

Comment: What pointer in the second example do you consider to be uninitialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare your `char *`:

```
char *str;
```

And then you give it as an argument to the function `strcmp()`:

```
if (strcmp(mat[j][trace[j]], str) < 0)
```

However `str` wasn't given any value in the meantime, it is ***undefined***.

Comment: then why the other piece of code works while the pointer is also uninitialized?

Comment: @AXE47: Accidents happen.

Comment: Undefeined Behavior can do anything, including appearing to work perfectly sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher's code is perfectly OK with no uninitialized pointer access whatsoever.

On the first iteration of the `for` loop, the variable `min_idx` is guaranteed to be -1 (set to that value a few lines above). By a mechanism that is called *short-circuit evaluation* (look that up in case you don't know what it is), the `strcmp` part of the `if`-clause that would actually use the uninitialized pointer `min_word` will only be evaluated when `min_idx` is anything else but -1.

On any following iterations of the `for`-loop, `min_word` is actually initialized.

Comment: ok got it thank you it's all about the order of the conditions in the `if` statement so the expression will be evaluated from the left to right and that grantee in the first iteration the pointer will not be used because of the variable `min_idx` will pass the condition and inside it the pointer is initialized.

Comment: @AXE47 exactly.